# Como faço pra criar link DESTROY com Slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Estou começando com Rails, e não estou conseguindo criar link para deletar um "post" do site.

Segue como estão os links `new` e `edit`

```
p.btn = link_to "Editar informações", edit_property_path(@property) if current_user == @property.user

p.btn = link_to "Editar imagens", new_property_media_content_path(@property) if current_user == @property.user

p.btn = link_to "Excluir
", property_path(@property) if current_user == @property.user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

Mostra o erro:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Comment: Bom Dia! Poderia mostrar o código todo da sua index.html.slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, está errado a forma que vc está usando a verificação dentro do link `Excluir`. Vale lembra que o `link_to` é um método então o que você manda para ele são os parâmetros, não deve colocar a verificação ali para mostrar ou não o link.

Segue seu exemplo refatorado:

`if current_user == @property.user
  p.btn= link_to "Editar informações", edit_property_path(@property) 
  p.btn= link_to "Editar imagens", new_property_media_content_path(@property)
  p.btn= link_to 'Excluir', property_path(@property), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}`

Comment: Olá Jean, obrigado pela resposta!! Acabei resolvendo com "= link_to "Excluir", property_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Tem certeza que deseja excluir este imóvel?'} if current_user == @property.user"  Veja que sem "(@property)". Assim a verificação if current_user == @property.user funciona e o link só aparece pro usuário que postou o imovel.. Abraço